# How do I accept a self-signed certificate with a Java using SSLSocket

Tags: java, android

I spend so much time browsing internet to find solution.99% of samples are for HTTPS, but i need to make my code to work with SSL server. I can not extract license from it, and license is self-signed. I try to make following code to work:

```
SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(); 
trustAllHosts();

// Get Socket from factory 
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("192.168.0.66", 2555); 

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new 
        OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out.write("username");
out.flush();
out.write("password");
out.flush();
```

Im getting: Not trusted server certificate

I found this code

```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                            String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                            String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }
    } };
```

But not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't apply it. It is insecure. Add the certificate to your truststore.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reply. I have no choice. Its a hardware device, i dont have certificate itself that i can add it.

But i fixed it by using

```
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
} };
    context.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good sample [here](https://blog.alcor.se/index.php/2013/08/09/using-java-to-connect-with-sslsocket-trusting-all-certificates/)

**Warning : this code is not safe**

What we're doing is ignoing the certificate

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
} };
context.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

SocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
...
```

remember to use this line

```
SocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
```

instead of

```
SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```