# How can I get hold of the server's certificate at run time when opening an SSLSocket in a Java client?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm writing a [Gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_(protocol)) client in Java. Two parts of the [Gemini spec](https://gemini.circumlunar.space/docs/specification.html) are relevant here:

> Servers MUST use TLS...

> ...the strongly RECOMMENDED approach is to implement a lightweight "TOFU" certificate-pinning system which treats self-signed certificates as first-class citizens.

By following this answer [How do I accept a self-signed certificate with a Java using SSLSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011348/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-using-sslsocket) I can successfully connect to Gemini servers with self-signed certificates.

But to implement the "TOFU" (trust on first use) requirement I should get hold of the server's certificate to validate that it hasn't changed on subsequent requests. **How do I get the certificate?**

The code I have is:

```
// On startup
try{
   m_sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
   m_sslContext.init(
      null,
      new TrustManager[]{
         new X509TrustManager(){
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){
               return new X509Certificate[] {};
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted( X509Certificate[] chain, String authType ) throws CertificateException
            {}

            public void checkServerTrusted( X509Certificate[] chain, String authType ) throws CertificateException
            {}
         }
      },
      null
   );
}
catch( NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException x )
{
   // error handling
}

// On fetching a Gemini URL:
Socket socket = m_sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket( host, port );
// ...read and write the socket
```

Comment: It is the first element in the `chain[]` passed to `checkServerTrusted()`.

Comment: 'This model is by no means perfect, but it is not awful': I disagree. It would be significantly better, although still awful, if the user was asked to accept the certificate on its first appearance, as well as when it changes. As it is, it is fundamentally insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store every server certificate and get it afterwords with a custom TrustManager.

An example setup would be:

```
public class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    private final Map<Integer, List<X509Certificate>> serverCertificates = new HashMap<>();
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        serverCertificates.put(counter++, Arrays.asList(x509Certificates));
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    public Map<Integer, List<X509Certificate>> getServerCertificates() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(serverCertificates);
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );

MyTrustManager myTrustManager = new MyTrustManager();
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{myTrustManager}, null);

// execute some https requests...
// and get the cached server certificates
Map<Integer, List<X509Certificate>> serverCertificates = myTrustManager.getServerCertificates();
```

Comment: He needs the custom `TrustManager` so he can accept the certifiate. Getting it out of the session, or the third way you didn't mention via a `HandshakeCompletionListener` callback, is too late in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have corrected my answer

Comment: Well as a matter of fact he should get the `SSLSession` from the `SSLSocket`. There's no guarantee otherwise that the session belongs to the socket.